# How to hide a div if it does not have 2 css classes at the same time?

Tags: jquery

There are about 20 div tags on the page, in which several classes are indicated (but all have the class "delivery-table-item", it is required). How to hide div in which at the same time there are no 2 necessary classes. I wrote a small script, but it hides all the divs at once, where did I make a mistake?

```
var deliveryVal = $('#f-select-delivery').val();
var statusVal = $('#f-select-status').val();
var dti = $('.delivery-table-item');
if( dti.not('.' + deliveryVal) && dti.not('.' + statusVal) ){
  $('.delivery-table-item').hide();
}
```

Comment: `if( ! $('.delivery-table-item').hasClass('deliveryVal') && ! $('.delivery-table-item').hasClass('statusVal') )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do it in one line as following

```
$('.delivery-table-item:not(.deliveryVal) ,.delivery-table-item:not(.statusVal)').hide();
```

your solution is wrong because 
your if condition you select
divs dosen't have `deliveryVal` class

```
$('.delivery-table-item').not('.deliveryVal')
```

and divs dosen't have `statusVal` class

```
$('.delivery-table-item').not('.statusVal') )
```

and do nothing with them 
then inside the if body you hide all divs using following statement

```
   $('.delivery-table-item').hide();
```

so at the end your solution is like check there is divs dosen't have `statusVal` class and there is divs dosen't have `statusVal` class then hide all divs

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```js
$('.delivery-table-item:not(.deliveryVal), .delivery-table-item:not(.statusVal)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="delivery-table-item statusVal">Item + Status</div>
<div class="delivery-table-item deliveryVal">Item + Delivery</div>
<div class="delivery-table-item deliveryVal">Item + Delivery</div>
<div class="delivery-table-item statusVal deliveryVal">Item + Status + Delivery</div>
<div class="delivery-table-item statusVal">Item + Status</div>
<div class="someOtherClass">Some other class</div>
```